# How to cache items which are returned by a list query? Using EHCache?

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

i am successfully able to cache results for queries that retrieve a single value.

```
@Cacheable(cacheName = "resourceCache")
public Resource find(int id) throws ResourceNotFoundException{
 ...
}
```

But for effiency reasons i need to implemented a method that effectively queries the database to retrieve a list of resources and look into the cache if possible elements already exist and if not put these in the cache.

How could i implement this? Any suggestions, hints or tips are appreciated?

Comment: Which JPA provider are you using?

Comment: We are using Spring JDBC template, so this returns the correct Object.